# What is the effective maximum payload throughput for USB in Full Speed?

Tags: performance, usb

USB Full speed has a speed of 12 MBit/second = 1,5 MByte/s.

But within these 12 MBit also a lot of extra data is transmitted which is not payload, like token, endpoint address, CRC5, CRC16, Acknowledge, SOF + EOF packets, etc.. Additionally the bus manager reserves 10% of a frame for Control Transfers.

See [Interrupt Transfer](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_g_interrupt.gif)
in [USB Made Simple Part 3](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_3.htm)

When I have an USB endpoint in Interrupt mode with a polling interval of 1 ms then I can transmit 64 bytes per frame = 64kByte / second.

But what if I have 2 endpoints with 1 ms polling?
Then the host will poll both endpoints within 1 ms so I have a total throughput of 128 kByte/s?

And when the host is polling 15 IN endpoints simulataneously that would result in 15 * 64 kByte = 960 kByte/s?

(Let's suppose for simplicity that there are no OUT transfers)

First question: 
Although searching a lot I could not find a website talking about the maximum effective payload throughput at Full Speed.

Second question:
Full speed allows a maximum of 64 byte / packet and a minimum poll interval of 1 ms. If I want to transfer the maximum possible payload via IN transfer, should I use multiple endpoints and spread the data transmission over these endpoints? With how many endpoints do I get to the limit?

Third question:
I see that in a Bulk transfer the host requests IN data more often than once per millisecond. Does this mean that Bulk is faster than Interrupt transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a partial answer in the USB 2.0 specification at chapter 5.7.4 and 5.8.4:

The protocol overhead is 13 bytes for Bulk transfers: (3 SYNC bytes, 3 PID bytes, 2 Endpoint + CRC bytes, 2 CRC bytes, and a 3-byte interpacket delay) and 19 bytes for Interrupt transfers (5 SYNC bytes, 5 PID bytes, 2 Endpoint + CRC bytes, 2 CRC bytes, and a 5-byte interpacket delay)

If a data payload of 64 bytes is used the max bandwidth is 1.216.000 Bytes/s for Bulk transfers. This means that one frame of 1 ms can transfer 1216 bytes = 19 blocks of 64 byte.

Interrupt endpoints are polled at a maximum interval of once per millisecond, so the maximum payload will be 64kB/s or less.

But these values are theory. The document states that bit stuffing is ignored. Also the 10% bandwidth reserved for Control transfers is ignored here. And for Interrupt endpoints the maximum throughput will be 64 byte per millisecond = 64 kByte / second.

Another interesting article about the speed measured in the **real life** of different Full speed devices and different operating systems is very interesting because it differs extremely from the theoretical values especially for Windows.

Paul measured a maximum speed of 1 Megabyte/second, but in the OUT direction.

http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/benchmark_usb_serial_receive.html

and

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_serial.html

Comment: Interrupt endpoints can only send one 64 byte packet every 1ms. Thus the limit is about 64kB/sec, after overhead.

Comment: You can send an interrupt packet to multiple endpoints in one frame in USB2 FS. There's a lot of overhead but f.ex. with 3 OUT endpoints in device, I've managed ~160kBps throughput (3x 64 byte packets at 1000 frames per second is ~192kBps). Tests suggest it's linearly scalable, so with max 15 OUT endpoints you could theoretically get ~768kBps overheaded included (no overhead ~960 kBps). Single endpoint BULK though would give the highest thruput at around ~1MBps.

Answer (score 2):

> Third question: I see that in a Bulk transfer the host requests IN data more often than once per millisecond. Does this mean that Bulk is faster than Interrupt transfer?

A *lot* faster. You can reach about 1 MByte/sec with a single bulk endpoint - which is also the maximum throughput you can get for USB Full speed.

In a nutshell: If your application wants to tansfer data as fast as possible use bulk endpoints.